# How do I get out of a boot loop with an iPhone with a broken power button?

Tags: iphone, ios

How do I get out of a boot loop with an iPhone with a broken power button?

Things I have tried that didn't work:

- I've tried draining the battery and then restarting it;
- I've tried connecting it to the computer but the computer doesn't recognize it as a device.

It's an iPhone 4 running iOS 7 if that additional information helps.

Answer (score 2):

ok, now i have this same problem but have found a solution that is not for the people who are shallow to technology...

Step 1: Connect your iPhone 30-Pin cable to your computer. (lightning adapter for iPhone 5 and up)

Step 2: Wait for the device to begin another loop.

Step 3: When another loop begins, hold the home button, volume up button, and plug the charger in.

Step 4: Fix whatever is making the device loop.

Answer (score 1):

1. Let it run out of battery.
2. Open iTunes.
3. Connect it to your computer and hold the home button as you plug it in.

   This should enter DFU and iTunes will prompt to restore it.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a Windows or Mac computer, you can use the [redsn0w jailbreak tool](http://redsn0wjailbreak.com). Once you have downloaded redsn0w, [follow these instructions](http://www.iclarified.com/entry/index.php?enid=23009) to put your iPhone into DFU mode.

(The screenshots are taken on Windows, but IIRC it works on Macs too.)

Answer (score 0):

If the power button is stuck on mechanically, then you may need to disassemble the phone and try to fix it. Not for the squeamish. There are several DIY help sites on the web. Here is one.

http://www.imore.com/iphone-diy-repair-ultimate-guide-fixing-stuck-or-broken-power-buttons

Answer (score 0):

RecBoot is often useful in these situations.

[RecBoot for Mac](http://www.cydiaos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/RecBoot-2.2-Mac.zip)

[RecBoot for Windows](http://www.cydiaos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/RecBoot-1.3-WIN.zip)

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

- Connect one end of the USB cable to your computer, but let the other
  end not connect to your iPhone. Turn your iPhone off.
- When the phone    is off, hold down the home button and connect the
  other end of USB    cable (which should still be attached to your
  computer) to the dock    connector.

Alternatively you can [download recboot](http://cydiapie.com/download-recboot-for-windowsmac-to-put-iphone-to-recovery-mode/) to fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

My old iPhone 4s had a reboot loop and also the power button is broken.
I tried to switch to recovery mode and that's how it worked for me after hours and month:

1. Let your phone run out of battery & download RecBoot
2. Update iTunes, start iTunes.
3. Press Home button while you plug in the USB to your iPhone/iPad
4. Start RecBoot and press "Enter recovery mode".
5. There will be several popups of iTunes asking for restore and so on. I installed a new blank iOS version, and it's working again, after 6 months!

Also there will be a new screen with "iTunes" and Lightning adapter—that's the right way.

Answer (score -1):

If the power button is stuck on mechanically, then you may need to disassemble the phone and try to fix it. Not for the squeamish.

Answer (score -1):

You can kick your iPhone into DFU mode with [Recboot](http://www.cydiawater.com/download-recboot-to-kick-an-iphone-into-recovery-mode/) easily.

Answer (score -1):

Follow this guide to [Fix iOS 9 Jailbreak Bootloop](http://www.guidesbeat.com/how-to-fix-ios-9-jailbreak-bootloop-blod-in-few-steps/) (BLoD) in few steps

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.